# In Angular/RxJs, how do I bundle http requests so that one bundle contains multiple requests (http://test/1, http://test/2, etc.)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was looking at the `bufferTime` rxjs operator, and essentially want to use it to bundle http requests (`this.http.get<string>('http://test/?id={num}'))`. {num} is 1 - 4. What I want, is to bundle these requests every 2 seconds. So if 2 requests are made within 2 seconds, they look like:

`this.http.get<string>('http://testUrl?id=1')` and `this.http.get<string>('http://testUrl?id=2')` and they will be sent as 1 request to the server (the bundling that I was referring to). The server will receive `'http://testUrl?id=1,2'`

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Could you please include a code snippet where you tried to acheive that?

Comment: @ramden I just tried the answer below from CozyAzure. You can use this as a reference for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I modified the code a bit. Now the two request bodies are merged into one body with an array. Every 3 seconds a set of request bodies are sent along with the url:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscriber, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators/debounceTime';
import { buffer } from 'rxjs/operators/buffer';

interface ReportRunStatus {
    status: any;
}

interface RequestWithObserver {
    request: number;
    observer: Subscriber<ReportRunStatus>;
}

const DEBOUNCE_TIME = 3000;

@Injectable()
export class WelcomeService {
    private requests = new Subject<RequestWithObserver>();
    private bufferTrigger = new Subject<null>();
    private requestBuffer = this.requests.pipe(buffer(this.bufferTrigger.pipe(debounceTime(DEBOUNCE_TIME))));

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.subscribeBufferRequests();
    }

    public getConfig(id: number) {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            this.bufferTrigger.next(null);

            this.requests.next({
                request: id,
                observer
            });
        });
    }

    public subscribeBufferRequests() {
        this.requestBuffer.subscribe((requests) => {
            const requestsData = requests.map((r) => r.request);
            this.http.post('getMovie', requestsData).subscribe((response) => {
                requests.forEach((requestItem, i) => {
                    requestItem.observer.next(response[i]);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`forkJoin` allows you to fire your requests in parallel, hence "bundle" your requests.

First create the array of Observables with your delay:

```
let obs = Array
    .from({length: 100}, (v, k) => k + 1)
    .map(x =>
        this.http.get<string>('http://test/{x}')
            .pipe(concatMap(item => of(item.pipe(delay(2000)))))
    );
```

Then just use `forkJoin` to fire them:

```
forkJoin(obs)
    .subscribe(x=>{
        console.log(x)//an array of response from HTTP
    })
```

The above code is only going to complete in  `2*(100-1)` = 198 seconds

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above but the page still makes two separate http requests. The requirement is that the bundled request is only one, and it contains multiple requests.

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai how is it gonna be one request, as each of it is an individual, standalone http request? If you only want to fire *one* http request, then you need to make sure your API supports it. and then your end point wouldnt be `http://test/1/` already.

Comment: I see that my original post wasn't clear, and that's of course my fault. Apparently, the requirements were that I aggregate multiple request bodies, not the whole request itself. I provided what worked for me above.